NestJS/Bull Queue consumers doesnt trigger properly
I have a simple queue consumer below.


@Processor('action')
export class ActionConsumer {
  constructor() {}

  @Process()
  async transcode(job: Job<any>) {
    console.log('action:', job.data);
    
    return { status: 'ok' };
  }
}



And here's my controller:


        this.actionQueue.add(
          {
            type: 'n',
            details: _details,
          },
          {
            repeat: {
              every: 100,
              limit: 3,
            },
          },
        );



I also tried like this :


        for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
          this.actionQueue.add({
            type: 'n',
            details: _details,
          });
        }



And the issue is when i use a brand new redis service it works completely fine.But after some time it starts to break apart.
The console log on the queue consumer let's say i wanted to trigger it for 3 times i only can see 2 console.logs on terminal (sometimes 1) but i can clearly see on bull dashboard all the queues have been processed successfully but it doesnt trigger the consumer method.


